# Azure KUSTO statment fails with "No tabular statement found"

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Can someone tell me why this Kusto statement in Log Analytics fails with "no tabular statement found"?

```
let eventcnt = Event
| where TimeGenerated > ago(10m)
```

I can run this query and a table of data is returned:

```
Event
| where TimeGenerated > ago(10m)
```

Comment: The actual error message is "No tabular expression statement found"

Comment: I often have to delete the default comments in generated KQL statements for them to work. It makes sense to add comments, but doesn't make sense to break the default query as a result.

Answer (score 26):

RE: your first code snippet: it's like you define a function in your program, but you don't actually do anything else in your program (and you don't call that function in your program).

it's the same with `let` statements and queries: if you want to use what you've just defined, you need to include it in your query. for example:

```
let eventcnt = Event
| where TimeGenerated > ago(10m);
eventcnt
```

Comment: I forgot the semicolon. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

App Insights log explorer gave me this error when there was a blank line between variable declaration and use.

### Works

```
let eventcnt = Event
| where TimeGenerated > ago(10m);
eventcnt
```

### Doesn't work

```
let eventcnt = Event
| where TimeGenerated > ago(10m);

eventcnt
```

Comment: Thanks! You saved a lot of time troubleshooting.

Comment: Can someone explain why the empty line breaks the execution?

Comment: this blows my mind...

Comment: Use // instead of white line works!

Answer (score 4):

For other facing this issue, it may as well belong to a missing ";" - a terminator semicolon. For the OP's example, this did not solve it - but it may help others facing the same error message.