# How to store output of KQL query in a variable

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

This code:

```
let myvar = Usage| where IsBillable == true| distinct DataType;
```

throws an error

> no tabular expression found

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62223667/7861807

Answer (score 0):

`let` is used for Ad-Hoc definitions, in a query's scope.
Your code does not contain a query, only a `let` statement.

You can use it as following:

```
let myvar = Usage | where IsBillable | distinct DataType;
myvar
```

P.S.
`IsBillable == true` can be shortand to `IsBillable`

Comment: Thanks David. The above query give the name of the tables where data is getting reported. So i wanna iterate through the myvar array and get resource ID.

Comment: the out put of above query is a array of strings. Each string is name of a table.

Comment: "InsightsMetrics
AzureMetrics
Perf
VMProcess
VMBoundPort
VMComputer
VMConnection
Event
AzureNetworkAnalytics_CL
StorageBlobLogs
WVDAgentHealthStatus
WVDManagement
WVDFeeds
StorageFileLogs
StorageTableLogs
WVDConnections
WVDCheckpoints
WVDErrors
WVDConnectionNetworkData
WVDHostRegistrations" =================================================
 for each in myvar {wvderrors| distinct _ResourceId}

Comment: Please follow SO guidelines. Your original question was answered,. Accept the answer, delete these comments and use a new post for any other question you still have.